# Performing segue taking up too much time

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, grand-central-dispatch

I have a `-[self performsSegueWithIdentifier:..]` method in my app. It is called after I click the "GO" button in the keypad. Since an API is being called at that moment, it needs about 5 seconds to load the data. So, I put an `-endEditing` command after in the `-buttonAction`. I have also put in an ActivityIndicator. I have tried two methods.

1.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toSecond" sender:self];
});
```

2.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toSecond" sender:self];
});
```

In the first method, I got the keypad to disappear and the ActivityIndicator to start animating. But it takes about 20 seconds to move to the next ViewController (I have checked with breakpoints: the time for the app to move from last command in `-prepareForSegue:` to the first command in the next ViewController is about 15-18 seconds).
In the second method, the transition doesn't take any time, but the `-shouldEndEditing` part and `-startAnimating` part are not being executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 5 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toSecond" sender:self];
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly..can you briefly tell me how this works and what is the significance of multiplying with 5?

Comment: 5 means 5 seconds here per your request, and how it works is described at https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html